# Animate on Scroll JS

Tags: javascript, animation, onscroll

I am new to JavaScript and trying to add some animations on scroll to a site.

I have multiple divs each with a unique class name and all with the same **.section** class.

I want to animate each **.section** on scroll without triggering the other **.sections**

```
<section class="home__one section></section>
<section class="home__two section></section>
<section class="home__three section></section>
<section class="home__four section></section>
```

```
$(window).on("scroll",function(){
    var winTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    var section = $(".section").offset().top;

    if(winTop >= section-400) {
      $(".section").addClass("animate");
    };
});
```

The code above obviously triggers every **.section** when the first reaches it's position on scroll.

I can't get my head around how I would trigger one **.section** as it comes into view.

I may be doing this the complete wrong way, so if I am, your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Use IDs and not classes if you are looking for separate functionalities.

Comment: @VTodorov Not exactly. At least not for this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, you need to loop through all the available sections and whichever section matches, you have to apply the class.

```
if (winTop >= section - 400) {
  $(".section").addClass("animate");
};
```

Plus, you don't have a `;` at the end of `if` statement.

Your final code will be like:

```
$(window).on("scroll", function(){
  var winTop = $(this).scrollTop();

  $(".section").each(function () {
    var section = $(this).offset().top;
    if(winTop >= section-400) {
      $(this).addClass("animate");
    }
  });
});
```

I would suggest removing the class `animate` from all the other sections. So, change your code this way:

```
$(window).on("scroll", function(){
  var winTop = $(this).scrollTop();

  $(".section").removeClass("animate").each(function () {
    var section = $(this).offset().top;
    if(winTop >= section-400) {
      $(this).addClass("animate");
    }
  });
});
```

Also, once you start adding the class, you don't want the other ones to have the class in them. So, give a top value too.

```
$(window).on("scroll", function(){
  var winTop = $(this).scrollTop();

  $(".section").removeClass("animate").each(function () {
    var section = $(this).offset().top;
    if(winTop >= section-400) {
      $(".section").removeClass("animate");
      $(this).addClass("animate");
    }
  });
});
```

Working Snippet:

```js
$(window).on("scroll", function(){
  var winTop = $(this).scrollTop();

  $(".section").removeClass("animate").each(function () {
    var section = $(this).offset().top;
    if(winTop >= section-400) {
      $(".section").removeClass("animate");
      $(this).addClass("animate");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.section {
  height: 750px;
}
.animate {
  background: #960;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="home__one section">Section one</section>
<section class="home__two section">Section two</section>
<section class="home__three section">Section three</section>
<section class="home__four section">Section four</section>
```

**Preview:**

[image]

A demo that you can see working by scrolling slowly: [**JSBin Demo**](https://jsbin.com/sefodujeda/edit?html,css,js,output).

Comment: That is exactly what I was after and works a treat.  Thank you so much.

Comment: If I don't want the class to be removed, how do I rearrange this code? I'm getting a flickering on and off when I scroll :(

Comment: @Leanne You can try adding some kind of transitions... I'll give you another snippet. Behold. 

Comment: @Leanne Try this out: [**With transitions.**](https://jsbin.com/dumusotata/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: That didn't work. The class is being added and then removed on scroll. I want the class to stay added.

Comment: @Leanne Slight clarification needed. Do you want the class to stay? Oh I am sorry, just remove the line `$(".section").removeClass("animate");`. Didn't understand at first.

Comment: That's ok, Thank you for your help.
Have you ever used this for this kind of thing? https://silvestreh.github.io/onScreen/ I tried to implement that but it's gone way over my head.

Comment: @Leanne Sorry for my delayed response, as I am at the office. The `onScreen` is awesome and I have used it to do scroll based fun stuff. Yes, tell me what you want with it, glad to help you out.

Comment: I got it working on codepen, but it's not working on my local WordPress site.

**JS:**
`(function(d,w,$) {
    
    var os = new OnScreen({
        tolerance: 200,
        debounce: 25,
        container: window
    });
    
    os.on('enter', '.section', (element, event) => {
        element.classList.add("animate");
    });


})(document, window, jQuery);`

What am I doing wrong? Thank you so much, I really appreciate all your help and no worries about the delay :)

Comment: https://codepen.io/pixelboutiqueuk/pen/VgZxwZ This is my working version, but it's not working on my local WordPress.

Comment: @Leanne Ahhh, local wordpress? Okay... That demo looks good though.

Comment: Thanks. Yep local WordPress. Any suggestions as to why it wont work?

Comment: @Leanne Check for console errors, like $ not found or something?

Comment: @Leanne Woah... Are you running the code before the element gets loaded?

Comment: I think I am using ES6 and maybe need ES5?

Comment: @Leanne Ha, try it out. Worth trying it.

Comment: No I'm using ES5. I have no idea what's wrong with it! Grrrr

Comment: @Leanne Shall we take this offline from Stack Overflow? Shoot me a quick email may be? Email in my [website](https://praveen.science/).